# CoreData fetching prefetch data

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have a device catalogue which contains SkuDetails. I need to implement filter based on colors, price and storage.

for getting all the devices i created this function:

```
[[CoreDataManager sharedInstance] fetchWithEntity:@"DevicesCatalogue" Predicate:nil success:^(NSArray *fetchLists) {
        if(fetchLists) {
            NSMutableArray *filteredItems = [NSMutableArray new];
            NSSortDescriptor *valueDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
            filteredItems = (NSMutableArray *)[fetchLists sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:valueDescriptor]];
            DeviceDetails *deviceDetails = [[DeviceDetails alloc]init];
            NSLog(@"first filter item ");
            deviceDetails.devices = filteredItems;
            successBlock(deviceDetails);
        }
        else {
            failureBlock(nil);
        }
    }failed:^(NSError *error) {
        failureBlock(error);
    }];
```

for getting all the colors i created this:

```
+ (void)getAllColorsWithSuccess:(void (^)(NSArray *colorsList))successBlock
                         failureBlock:(void (^)(NSError * error))failureBlock  {


    [[CoreDataManager sharedInstance] fetchWithEntity:@"DevicesCatalogueSkuDetails" Predicate:nil success:^(NSArray *fetchLists) {
        if(fetchLists) {
            NSArray *colorsList  = [@[fetchLists,fetchLists] valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfArrays.colorCode"];
            NSLog(@"%@",colorsList);

            successBlock(colorsList);
        }
        else {
            failureBlock(nil);
        }
    }failed:^(NSError *error) {
        failureBlock(error);
    }];
}
```

vice versa i have added functions for storage and price also.

for filtering functionality , i need to know how can i prefetch data which is already fetch using predicate.

like, for getting devices between the range of prices, i created this function, which returns only those devices consist of prices:

```
NSPredicate * pricePredicate =  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY skuDetails.priceWithVat >= %f AND ANY skuDetails.priceWithVat <= %f",selectedSliderMinValue,selectedSliderMaxValue];
    [[CoreDataManager sharedInstance] fetchWithEntity:@"DevicesCatalogue" Predicate:pricePredicate success:^(NSArray *fetchLists) {
        if(fetchLists) {
            for (Devices *devices in fetchLists) {
                NSLog(@"name --- %@",devices.name);
            }
            [self resetAllArrays];
        }
    }failed:^(NSError *error) {

    }];
```

My question is that now i get array of devices how can i prefetch these devices to include more filter like for storage and colors? is it possible to refetch a CoreData which is already fetch with one predicate.

**

***- UPDATE:***
**

for filter i put this function but this basically changing params and calling again, but how can i call it based on my fetch data based on prices which contains only 2 devices.

```
-(void)getAllDevicesDetailBasedOnFilter{
    NSMutableArray *predicateArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    //DevicesCatalogueSkuDetails
    isColorSelected = YES;
    isBrandSelected = YES;
    isStorageSelected = YES;
    isPriceSelected = YES;
    if (isPriceSelected) {
        NSPredicate * pricePredicate =  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY skuDetails.priceWithVat >= %.f AND ANY skuDetails.priceWithVat <= %.f",minimumPriceValue,maximumPriceValue];
        [predicateArray addObject:pricePredicate];
    }
    if (isBrandSelected) {
        NSPredicate * brandPredicate =  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"brand = %@", @"Samsung"];
        [predicateArray addObject:brandPredicate];
    }

    if (isColorSelected) {
        NSPredicate * colorPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY skuDetails.color CONTAINS[cd] %@",@"Green"];
        [predicateArray addObject:colorPredicate];
    }

    if (isStorageSelected) {
        NSPredicate * colorPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY skuDetails.storage CONTAINS[cd] %@",@"256"];
        [predicateArray addObject:colorPredicate];
    }

    NSPredicate *compoundPredicate =  [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicateArray];
    [[CoreDataManager sharedInstance] fetchWithEntity:@"DevicesCatalogue" Predicate:compoundPredicate success:^(NSArray *fetchLists) {
        if(fetchLists) {

        }

    }failed:^(NSError *error) {

    }];

}
```

[image]

Comment: just create an appropriate fetch request with all of the required predicates for filtering and execute it. When the criteria change, simply repeat the process.

Comment: i updated the question can you please check @ Paulw11